# Menu item click in a navigation drawer intent to activity hosting a fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments, onclicklistener, menuitem, navigationview

Disclaimer: This is the first app I am building so I am learning the hard way to use fragments first, so my code is all over the place.

I have menu items inside a navigation view that loads fine however the menu item clicks don't work. It doesn't crash it just stares at me. I would like to use an intent to display a fragment and I am lost from changing and trying so many different options.

XML FOR NAV DRAWER & MENU ITEMS:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_pageone"
    android:background="@drawable/rygg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/primary_dark_color"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="com.android.nohiccupsbeta.pageone">

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_header_container"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/category_vodka"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_dark_color"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_gravity="start" >

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

JAVA:

public class pageone extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pageone);
        setupDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.drawermenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param item For the hamburger button
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.itemWhiskey:
                Intent whiskeyIntent = new Intent(pageone.this, whiskeyActivity.class);
                startActivity(whiskeyIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make sure the drawer open and closes in sync with UI visual
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mToggle.syncState();
    }

    /**
     * Function to make sure all the drawer open & closes properly
     */
    public void setupDrawer() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_pageone);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View closeView) {
                Toast.makeText(pageone.this, "Happy You Learned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onDrawerClosed(closeView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View openView) {
                Toast.makeText(pageone.this, "Effects Of Alcohol", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onDrawerOpened(openView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        MenuItem itemWhiskey = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.itemWhiskey);
        itemWhiskey.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem itemWhiskey) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Fragment effectsFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container2);
                if (effectsFragment == null) {
                    effectsFragment = new WhiskeyFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container2, effectsFragment).commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Whiskey");
                    itemWhiskey.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}

XML FOR FRAGMENT:

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container2"
    tools:context="com.android.nohiccupsbeta.WhiskeyFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag_whiskey_skin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"  />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more"
        android:padding="16dp"/>

</FrameLayout>

JAVA:

public class WhiskeyFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mWhiskeySkin;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, SavedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("WHISKEY EFFECTS");

        mWhiskeySkin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_whiskey_skin);
        mWhiskeySkin.setText(R.string.whiskey_skin);
        hasOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whiskey, container, false);
        hasOptionsMenu();
        return v;
    }
}

XML FOR SECOND ACTIVITY:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

JAVA:

public class whiskeyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_whiskey);
    }

    public class Whiskeyed {

        private String whiskeySkin;
        private String whiskeyBrain;

        public String getWhiskeySkin(){
            return whiskeySkin;
        }
        public String getWhikeyBrain(){
            return whiskeyBrain;
        }
        public void setWhiskeySkin(String whiskey_skin){
            this.whiskeySkin = whiskey_skin;
        }

        public void setWhiskeyBrain(String whiskeyBrain) {
            this.whiskeyBrain = whiskeyBrain;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using navigation drawer for the first time try integrating android studio default navigation activity, easy and understandable.
else if you want to try in this code let me know ,will help you.

Comment: Yes I would rather try to remedy this code...the hard way lol. Thank you I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to change to content of your `onNavigationItemSelected` of your `pageone.java`

from here:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    MenuItem itemWhiskey = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.itemWhiskey);
    itemWhiskey.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem itemWhiskey) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment effectsFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container2);
            if (effectsFragment == null) {
                effectsFragment = new WhiskeyFragment();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container2, effectsFragment).commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Whiskey");
                itemWhiskey.setChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

to here:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_pageone); // ID of your drawerLayout
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu1: // Change this as your menuitem in menu.xml.
            // Your fragment code goes here..
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment effectsFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container2);
            if (effectsFragment == null) {
                effectsFragment = new WhiskeyFragment();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container2, effectsFragment).commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Whiskey");
                itemWhiskey.setChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        break;
        case R.id.menu2: // Change this as your menuitem in menu.xml.
            // or Your fragment code goes here...
        break;
    }
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START, true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the progress. At this point the onCreateOptionsMenu (for top right corer) is the button that gives the reaction I want, however the navigiation menu item is not working yet. I have tried putting the code for the intent in the navigationItemSelected function after the fragment declaration but no cigar.